# How can I bind sample data from a variable of type List<string> inside a class to the XAML (design) page

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, data-binding

I've been making use of binding to sample data so that I can get a feel of what the app is going to look like during runtime.

Things have been going great until I had to bind to a List<>. I made a sample application to demonstrate the problem.

**Person.cs**

```
public string FullName { get; set; }
public int Age { get; set; }
public string Sex { get; set; }
public List<string> Friends { get; set; }
```

**MainViewModelSampleData.xaml**

```
<vm:MainViewModel
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:StackoverflowQuestion.ViewModels">


<vm:MainViewModel.Items>
    <vm:Person FullName="Homer Simpson" Age="45" Sex="Male" />
    <vm:Person FullName="Bruce Wayne" Age="32" Sex="Male" Friends="" />
</vm:MainViewModel.Items>
```

I can get the design view to correctly shows the *string FullName*, *int Age*, and *string Sex*.

What I don't know and can't figure out is how to bind data from List<`string`> Friends so that I can view it on the design view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is 'extracting' the Friends value

```
<vm:Person FullName="Bruce Wayne" Age="32" Sex="Male">
        <vm:Person.Friends>
            <x:String>First</x:String>
            <x:String>Second</x:String>
        </vm:Person.Friends>
```

Depending on the version of App x:String is necessary or the literal directly

```
<vm:Person FullName="Bruce Wayne" Age="32" Sex="Male">
        <vm:Person.Friends>
            First
            Second
        </vm:Person.Friends>
```

And the last option is add the following namespace

```
xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"

<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.DataContext>
    <local:Person Name="ww">
        <local:Person.Friends>
            <System:String>one</System:String>
            <System:String>one</System:String>
        </local:Person.Friends>
    </local:Person>
```

Comment: Thanks @Juan, I tried that but it doesn't seem to work. I get a blue squiggly line saying, "String is not supported in a Windows Phone Silverlight project"

Comment: In that case try the other option

Comment: Still doesn't work. Now it says, "The TypeConverter for "List'1" does not support converting from a string."

Comment: The last option that can be in the answer